# ORM for Multiple relational databases in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let say that I have 3 models in an App and I need to get the price of the item using the Order Class. How can I achieve such a function? Also, since the OrderItem has Many-to-Many fields, I would like to seek help on how to loop from all the items and get the price.

Models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Views.py

```
def get_price(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    return render(request, 'ecommpage/history.html', {'order':order})
```

History.html

```
{% extends 'account/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content%}
{%for order_item in order.item.all() %}
{{order_item.items.price}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Error message:

**Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'order.items.all()'**

When I tried to print the function get_price, It does not show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `items` is **ManyToManyField**, you have to do:

```
for order_item in order.items.all():
    print(order_item.item.price)
```

```
def get_price(request):
    order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)

    for order_item in order.items.all():
        print(order_item.item.price)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. I would like to know if this will work also on the templates?

Comment: I am not able to implement the code on templates. It shows nothing!

Comment: Please edit your question(or create new one) and provide us the template code. If ```get_price``` is your View for your Template, it should return ```render``` with at least ```order``` in context. Then, in the template, you can loop over ```order.items.all()```

Comment: Remove ```()``` from ```all()```

Comment: I've removed the **()**, but it does show nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229664/discussion-between-token-and-ian).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to loop to get all the prices. You can simply [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) them like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
total_price = order.items.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))['total']
```